# How to see database values in html

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, database

I'm trying to visualize sql database. At the end I hope to see some kind of chart but I can't transform values from php to js and html. In my database are two entries from the same form. First file is a php file and I called it "**read.php**":

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","databasename");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tablename");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[] = array(
            'join_date' => $row['join_date'],
            'column1' => $row['column1'],
            'column2' => $row['column2'],
            'column3' => $row['column3'],
            'column4' => $row['column4']
          );
        echo json_encode($data);    
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

When I open this file I see it as json. I would like to see these columns in a html file so I made "**readjson.html**":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2> Database in html</h2>

One: <p1 id="origname1"></p1><br>  
two: <span id="origname2"></span><br>  

<script type="text/javascript" > 
var baza = "<?php ($data )[http://localhost/read.php]; ?>";

document.getElementById("origname1").innerHTML=baza[0].join_date + ", " + baza[1].column1 + ", " + baza[0].column2 + ", " + baza[0].column3 + ", " + baza[0].column4;
document.getElementById("origname2").innerHTML=baza[1].join_date + ", " + baza[1].column1 + ", " + baza[1].column2 + ", " + baza[1].column3 + ", " + baza[1].column4;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the readjson.html I see:

*Database in html
One: undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined
two: undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined*

Instead of *undefined* I would like to see the database entries. Please help.

Comment: Do you want it as JSON?  Or do you just want the visual version of the database?  i.e. would you accept a solution that does not make use of JSON?

Comment: Why do you write `($data )[http://localhost/read.php];` ???

Comment: You're reading the table in one PHP script, but attempting to display it in a different HTML file. This won't work. Additionally, I can't make head nor tail of this `<?php ($data )[http://localhost/read.php]; ?>`.

Comment: What is `var baza = "<?php ($data )[http://localhost/read.php]; ?>";` Is that a strange attempt at using some magical Ajax rather than an actually existing Ajax call?  Lookup Ajax and JQuery.

Comment: Don't mock his magic!

Comment: forget "($data )[http://localhost/read.php];" 
I only want to see data from my database into .html and any future entry should also been see in the same .html file. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Firsly, I want to know how you came up with this:

`"<?php ($data )[http://localhost/read.php]; ?>";`

This is no PHP syntax. What you want is to include that file, and in `read.php` do not print  `json_encode`

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","databasename");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tablename");

$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[] = array(
            'join_date' => $row['join_date'],
            'column1' => $row['column1'],
            'column2' => $row['column2'],
            'column3' => $row['column3'],
            'column4' => $row['column4']
          );
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Then including it:

```
<?php
include 'read.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2> Database in html</h2>

One: <p1 id="origname1"></p1><br>  
two: <span id="origname2"></span><br>  

<script type="text/javascript" > 
var baza = JSON.parse(<?php echo '"' . json_encode($data) . '"'; ?>);

document.getElementById("origname1").innerHTML=baza[0].join_date + ", " + baza[1].column1 + ", " + baza[0].column2 + ", " + baza[0].column3 + ", " + baza[0].column4;
document.getElementById("origname2").innerHTML=baza[1].join_date + ", " + baza[1].column1 + ", " + baza[1].column2 + ", " + baza[1].column3 + ", " + baza[1].column4;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't assure you this will work but do try it out!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I found "<?php ($data )[http://localhost/read.php]; ?>" somewhere on the internet, actually I do not really know what I'm doing :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I found "<?php ($data )[http://localhost/read.php]; ?>" somewhere on the internet, actually I do not really know what I'm doing :) 

I only want to see data from my database into .html and any future entry should also been see in the same .html file. I am open for every solutions but the last didn't help